# How to display one of the fields once in drupal views?

Tags: views, entities

I have created a gallery view using nid as contextual filter, all images have the same album title. I need to output the album title field once. How can this be done?

I'm using views 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can group the rows of the view by the title (Format: Unformated list - Settings)

Answer (score 4):

Select settings in **Format** field,and select the title under Group field selectlist.
[image]